# How data is getting mapped in Elastic search in ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am new to the ELK and i am in the progress of learning it. In my project, they are importing the data from Amazon S3 -> File Beat -> logstash -> Elastic search -> Kibanna.

In the logstash file, they have directly importing the data and sending to the Elastic search something like below and there was no indexes mentioned in the config file,

```
output  elasticsearch 
{
hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
}
```

In Amazon s3, we have logs from Salesforce and in future we are going to implement from multiple sources.

In Elastic search, i could see 41 indexes(Used Get Curl script) is present. Assume if we keep the same setup in logstash, then all logs(Multiple sources) will be sent to elastic search in same manner. **I would like to know how the data is getting mapped to the particular index in elastic search ??**

In many tutorials, they have given indexes in the logstash config file so in kibanna we could see the index name along with timestamp. I have tried to check by placing a sample Mulesoft log file in Amazon S3 but i cant able to find those data in Kibanna. So shall i need to create one more new index with a name Mule along with mappings??

There is no ELK expert in my project so please guide me on how to approach this one or any references will be more helpful.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what is your question. Do you want to specify the name of the Elasticsearch index where logstash is outputting the data into? Then you'll need to set the `index` parameter of the Elasticsearch Output plugin (https://www.amazon.it/TP-Link-TL-PA4010-Powerline-Ethernet-HomePlug/dp/B01NARHG7X/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=powerline%2Btplink&qid=1586335985&sr=8-3&th=1)

Answer (score 1):

This page (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) documents Logstash's Elasticsearch output plugin.

As you can see in the Configuration Options section, the option `index` is **not** mandatory. If this option is not specified, its default-value is `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`.

With that being said, the documents will get indexed into indices with the prefix 'logstash-' followed by the date of ingestion. For example:

- logstash-2020.04.07
- logstash-2020.04.08

Since someone in your organization has chosen to go with the default value, this option can be left out. This explains why you can't find a particular index name in the Logstash configuration. If you need to index documents into different indices, then you'd have to set a particular value for the `index` option.

Elasticsearch will automatically create these indices with a dynamic mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) if you haven't setup an explicit mapping via index templates in advance. In order to see the data in kibana, you first need to create an index pattern matching the index name.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have checked it using GET Curl script and i don't see any index with the name as "logstash-date". I can see index with the name as sf-Apex something like this, which is around 40 similar Index is present and also it has the mapping part. Please let me know how to approach further.

Comment: What fo you mean with "has the mapping part". You need to be careful with the term "mapping" in Elasticsearch. What exactly do you mean with that? Also, you'd need ti share the exact Logstash pipeline configuration in order to let us help you. Thus please update your original question with these information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i have figured how they have implemented. They have used the Lambda function to pull the logs from a application and save it in S3 and then pushes the logs to the particular index directly in ES. Thanks your help. One more small doubt - if i create a cron job in the logstash conf file to pull the data from Mule application the the data will be saved in the elastic server?? So with the help of s3 output plugin i can save it in the s3 bucket instead of the elastic cloud ? https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-the-elastic-stack-for-observability-of-mulesoft-cloudhub